# NodeJS Script & setInterval with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, fastify

so I am stuck and have not found a ton of answers to lead me to the best solution.

I have a node js app, serving APIs with a MongoDB as db. So within the request I created a setInterval, that is update the data every 30 seconds. I did this so that if there are requests every second, the node js app isnt querying the MongoDB server with the same request since its the same data.

But I believe this has led to a memory leak.

What would be the best way to achieve this so I can push the data directly from memory since its grabbed/updated every 30 seconds, while allowing garbage collection to work properly.

Below is the api request.

```
let data = null;

//interval
setInterval(async () => {
    try {
        data= await collection.find({
          data: { $ne: 'old'},
            $or: [
                { "currentRanks.minuteTokenRank": {$lt: 51} },
                { "currentRanks.fiveMinuteTokenRank": {$lt: 51} },
                { "currentRanks.fifteenMinuteTokenRank": {$lt: 51} },
                { "currentRanks.thirtyMinuteTokenRank": {$lt: 51} },
                { "currentRanks.hourlyTokenRank": {$lt: 51} },
                { "currentRanks.dailyTokenRank": {$lt: 51} },
                { "currentRanks.weeklyTokenRank": {$lt: 51} }
            ]
        }).lean();

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return;
    }
  }, 30000);

export async function main(req, reply) {
    try {
        let datares= data;
        reply.status(200).send(datares);
        datares= null;
    } catch {(err) => {
        reply.status(500).send({ message: err.message })
        console.log('err', err.message)
        }
    }
  //console.log('Get Data')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The command `db.serverStatus()` ([docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/)) can provide an overview of memory usage.
check the memory usage by this command: `db.serverStatus().mem`